# SSHEXEC task has a script calling in command in Ant, called from Jenkins, times out after 2 hours

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, ssh, ant

From Jenkins, based on the target present in the ANT XML, i will invoke that target. That target has `SSHEXEC` task.

In that `SSHEXEC` task, command has calling of the script.

Basically script code goes like below:

```
waitForAggregationJobCompletion()
{
while [ 1 ]
do
# Checks for the condition

if [ #Condition] ;then
break;
fi

if [ #Different condition ]; then
break;
fi

done
waitForAggregationJobCompletion
```

Basically once this function "`waitForAggregationJobCompletion`" is called, it goes into while[1] loop & keep checking for the condition. Once if is satisfies the condition present in in "IF" condition, it should break.

This runs good if scripts runs for 1.5 hours. But if script is running for longer time, in Jenkins it will says it is still executing but where as on the Linux server, it wouldn't be running.

Is it due to `sshexec` task in ANT can hold the script process for only certain time? or do i need to add any parameters in `sshd_config` file before triggering this while[1] condition based scripts to run for longer time.

I have put logging re-direction in script & one echo statement to re-direct to `/dev/null`, but it didn't work out.

When I kept logging re-direction it printed that log with Date for close 2.10 hours & then there is no logging in that file.

Can you please help  me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if one of the tips mentioned in "[SSH timeout prevention – keep SSH sessions alive](https://www.bjornjohansen.no/ssh-timeout)"  by Bjørn Johansen

On the client side, for instance:

> you can edit your local SSH config file in `~/.ssh/config` and add the following line:

```
ServerAliveInterval 120
```

> This will send a “null packet” every 120 seconds on your SSH connections to keep them alive.

In a Jenkins context, that would be the `~/.ssh/config` of the user executing the job on the Jenkins slave.

---

But if you have access/control to the server side:

> add the following to your SSH daemon config in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on your servers to prevent the clients to time out – so they don’t have to modify their local SSH config:

```
ClientAliveInterval 120
ClientAliveCountMax 720
```

> This will make the server send the clients a “null packet” every 120 seconds and not disconnect them until the client have been inactive for 720 intervals (120 seconds * 720 = 86400 seconds = 24 hours).

Comment: Currently, i have added client parameters at my server in /etc/ssh/sshd_config. It is working. Thanks. At the client side, i..e, Jenkins side, if i add ServerAliveInterval as 120, will the connection be alive forever? Do i need add ServerAliveCountMax also, so that i can end the open ssh connection after some time.

Comment: @DheerajKumarY Yes, ServerAliveCountMax  might help on the client side.